# Is an oven heating element polarized?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, oven

I just took out an oven heating element without paying attention to which wire was hooked up to what end. Does it matter how I hook it back up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't expect it to be anything more than a resistive element so it shouldn't be polarized... but the maintenance manual is almost certainly available on the weB, free or for a small fee, so I'd suggest you check that.

Comment: Tupoghraploc eror fiixed; thanks for pointing it out.